# Node.js Express Callback Execution Question

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Just a quick technical question if any of you know the answer:

I'm writing some express middleware to capture clicks on a route. I don't care for this code to wait for the mongo insert to complete. Is it safe to put next() outside of the callback or do I risk callback execution being lost/interrupted?

```
const ClickCounter = (req, res, next) => {
     const insert = {
         path: req.path,
         ts: new Date()
     };

     console.time('click_counter');
     connector.save('Clicks', insert, (error, results) => {
        console.timeEnd('click_counter');
        if (error){
            console.trace('[Utils.ClickCounter] Error submitting click');
            console.warn(error);
        }
     });

     // placing outside of mongo query so client does not have to wait.
     next();
};
```

Comment: You can do that. But if there is any error while executing the code, your user will not know about it. 
But if you wait for save to complete operation, you will get the confirmation that it saved without error.

Comment: Hmmm so that callback could possibly be lost but the mongo operation itself will continue until complete? In this scenario for me the insert operation is more important than the callback but would be nice to log out any errors.

Comment: yes it will continue to run. callback is always important.